# I need to store an array of integers for configuration of a custom module - which of these is right?

Tags: 7

This is a list that is permanently recorded that should be able to change at a later time, either adding or removing items from the array at a user's discretion.

First method:

```
variable_set('module_listOfIntegers', serialize($arrayOfInts));
```

Second method:

```
$serialized = serialize($arrayOfInts);

$num_updated = db_update('module_config')
->fields(array(
  'listOfIntegers' => $serialized,
))
->condition('config_name', 'config_name, '==')
->execute();
```

And the final method could be creating a 2nd table with a single column where each row just holds the integer.  That seems a bit excessive for a simple array, though.

Comment: Both, depending on size of data and how frequently you need to read it. Do you have any practical problem that you face, with either of these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving module config settings, I use [variable_set()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) in conjunction with the [system_settings_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) function. Just also note that it and its companion [variable_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) do the serialize/unserialize for you, so, there is no need for you to be doing it.

Comment: Ah!  Alrighty.  That's probably just the easiest way to go, then.  Thank you, sir.